# Как получить итераторы начала и конца у временного объекта без создания его промежуточной копии?

Tags: c++, итераторы, rvalue

```
// Пример кода надуманный, только для демонстрации проблемы!

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> TransformVector(const std::vector<int>& source_vector) {
    std::vector<int> transform_vector;
    for (int item : source_vector) {
        transform_vector.push_back(item * item);
    }
    return transform_vector;
}

std::vector<int> VectorVector_to_TransformVector(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vv) {
    std::vector<int> flat_vector;
    for (std::vector<int> v : vv) {
        std::vector<int> transform_vector = TransformVector(v);
        flat_vector.insert(flat_vector.end(), transform_vector.begin(), transform_vector.end());
    }
    return flat_vector;
}

void PrintVector(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    for (int number : v) {
        std::cout << number << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv = {
            {1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
            {6,  7,  8,  9,  10},
            {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
            {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
    };

    std::vector<int> flat_vector = VectorVector_to_TransformVector(vv);
    PrintVector(flat_vector);

    return 0;
}
// Вывод: 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 400
```

В функции `VectorVector_to_TransformVector` приходится создавать временный объект `transform_vector`, чтобы в следующей строке получить итераторы начала и конца последовательности. Потому что если сделать так:

```
flat_vector.insert(flat_vector.end(), TransformVector(v).begin(), TransformVector(v).end());
```

то функция `TransformVector(v)` будет вызвана 2 раза. Существуют ли какие-нибудь приемы, чтобы провернуть такой трюк, позволяющий получить итераторы начала и конца у временного объекта и не создавать этот объект два раза?

Comment: Чем плохо давать имя временному объекту? Замечу что есть NRVO, конструктор копии/перемещения не будет вызываться в вашем коде.

Comment: В этом примере не требуется временный объект. ¿Зачем создавать плоский вектор, когда уже есть двухслойный?

Comment: @user7860670, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Если есть необходимость пройтись по всем элементам двухслойного вектора, как будто он плоский, то можно сделать специальный итератор и не создавать временного контейнера. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view

Comment: Вы заботитесь о временных объектах, но при эторм в цикле копируете векторы!

Comment: Никакой выгоды не даст вам решение вашего вопроса. Совсем.

Comment: @user7860670, решение хорошее, но только для C++20

Comment: @megorit, не обращайте внимание на приведенный выше код, он дан только для демонстрации проблемы (вопроса) и в остальном не имеет никакого смысла

Comment: Это решение для любого стандарта, кусок для ranges из С++20 приведен просто в качестве примера.

Comment: @user7860670, вы имеете ввиду свой итератор создать для обхода всех элементов?

Comment: Ну можно и так.

Comment: @user7860670, а какие еще варианты есть, кроме написания своего итератора? Для C++17 может быть готовые решения есть? Что-то типа std::ranges::views::join например?

Comment: В boost стоит заглянуть

Answer (score 1):

Более того, в последнем вызове это формально итераторы к *разным* контейнерам.

Не проще ли, если уж так хочется отдельной функции, что-то вроде

```
for(auto x: TransformVector(v)) flat_vector.push_back(x);
```

Или вообще так, без создания временного контейнера:

```
std::vector<int> VectorVector_to_TransformVector(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vv) {
    std::vector<int> flat_vector;
    for (std::vector<int> v : vv) {
        for(auto x: v) flat_vector.push_back(x*x);
    }
    return flat_vector;
}
```

Не думаю, что `insert` будет быстрее, особенно если предварительно `resize` на весь размер всех исходных векторов сделать.

Еще можно посмотреть в сторону стандартных алгоритмов, например, [`transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: нет никакого смысла модернизировать код из примера выше, так как он приведен здесь только для демонстрации проблемы - как получить два итератора (начала и конца контейнера) временного объекта, не создавая этот объект два раза и не выделяя под него специальную переменную.

Comment: Нет никакого смысла рассматривать сферического коня в вакууме.

Comment: не такой уж это и сферический конь, согласитесь, и в вашем коде скорее всего часто встречается, что вы итераторы у временного объекта забираете? С одним итератором получается довольно таки изящное решение, а с двумя побочный эффект и приходится создавать объект, мелочь конечно, но я и не говорил что мой вопрос претендует на роль паттерна проектирования:)

Comment: Сферический конь — обсуждение, как решить проблему без конкретного кода... Но вот вам еще один вариант: передавайте временный объект в еще одну функцию. На этот раз я по вашему совету не буду опускаться из горных высей идей в низменный мир кода :), думаю, идея понятна?

Comment: не очень понятно, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: `vector<int> temporary_object(); void add_vector(vector<int>&dest, const vector<int>& src) { dest.insert(dest.end(),src.begin(),src.end()); }  ...   add_vector(your_vector,temporary_object()); }` Так понятнее?